# Pandas multiple conditions filtering with or statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, filtering

Looking to see if someone know how to chain multiple conditions in pandas.... I am looking form something like this:

```
df[(df.col1>2)&df.col2<5) or (df.col5==5)&(df.col3>=78)]
```

so far I have found no solution that allows me to include an or condition like in my example.

Any help os appreciated1

Comment: What's wrong with `|` ? `df[((df.col1 > 2) & (df.col2 < 5)) | ((df.col5 == 5) & (df.col3 >= 78))]` Near identical example provided in [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36921951/15497888)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same as and have a character so dose or use the | for or statement
and sometimes pandas like more ()

```
df[((df.col1>2)&df.col2<5)) | ((df.col5==5)&(df.col3>=78))]
```